# Is this shadowing a variable in F#?

Tags: variables, f#, shadowing

```
        let print_scene (y, v) =
            do Console.Clear()

            let y, v = int y, int v    (* This is the code in question *)

            for j = 10 downto 0 do
                for i = 0 to 30 do
                    if (y + 1) = j && i = 15 then
                        Console.Write("b")
                    elif j = 0 || i = 0 || j = 10 || i = 30 then
                        Console.Write("*")
                    else
                        Console.Write(" ")
                Console.Write("\n")
            ignore(Console.ReadKey())
```

I don't understand what the `int` is doing in this code, what it is, or why it's there.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.int%5b%5et%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d

Comment: @glennsl - post as an answer so I can check it and upvote.

Comment: @glennsl great find! Google doesn't seem to index that page - it didn't appear for me even when searching for the first sentence in quotes: "Converts the argument to signed 32-bit integer". Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this is parameter shadowing.

```
let foo bar =
    let bar = bar * bar
    bar
```

This is absolutely fine in F#. A function parameter is being shadowed by a binding. Nothing is being changed - it just makes the original binding inaccessible.

The deeper problem lies in the `int`. Because `int` converts a type to an `Int32` you'd expect the function to take in anything that can be converted to `int`; either numbers or strings.
But -

```
  let print_scene (y, v) =
         let y, v = int y, int v 
         ()

    print_scene (1.0, "2.0")
    print_scene (1.0,  2.0) //this won't compile
```

The function parameters will be constrained from its first usage. Here, its type becomes:

```
float * string -> unit
```

This is because F# doesn't have [higher-kinded polymorphism](https://sidburn.github.io/blog/2016/03/24/higher-kinded-polymorphism).
You are probably better off being explicit about the type of parameters you want to accept, or inlining it, if being generic is important to you.

```
let inline print_scene (y, v) =
     let y, v = int y, int v 
     ()

print_scene (1.0, "2.0") 
print_scene (1.0, 2.0) //this works
```

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a function that takes a type that has a static member `op_Explicit` and returns an integer. `string` is the most common example of this:

```
int "108" // returns `108` as an integer
```

In VS Code, if you hover on `int` you'll see this:

[image]

If you call `print_scene("1", "2")` it should return the same output as `print_scene(1, 2)`.

This is shadowing:

```
let i = 1
let i = 2
```

This does not mutate `i`. I'll refer you to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39645319).

Comment: > If you call print_scene("1", "2") it should return the same output as print_scene(1, 2). 
Unfortunately, you can't do both.