# function with mutable arguments

Tags: f#

in F#, it's not allowed to have mutable argument with functions. but if I have a function like the following:

```
let f x =
    while x>0 do
      printfn "%d" x
      x <- x-1;;
```

when I compile this, I'm getting a compiler error.(not mutable) 
How would I fix this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pass-by-value semantics, you can use [parameter shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60137632/is-this-shadowing-a-variable-in-f).

Here, a shadowed (because it's the same name) mutable value `x` is declared on the stack.

```
let f x =
    let mutable x = x
    while x > 0 do
      printfn "%d" x
      x <- x - 1
```

For pass-by-reference semantics, you'll have to use a [reference cell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/reference-cells), which is a just a fancy way of passing an object which has a mutable field in it. It's similar to `ref` in C#:

```
let f x =
    while !x > 0 do
      printfn "%d" !x
      x := !x - 1
```

Using a reference cell:

```
let x = (ref 10)
f x
Debug.Assert(!x = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it like this:

```
let f x = [x.. -1..1] |> List.iter (printfn "%d")
```

If you want to keep the while loop, you could do this:

```
let f (x : byref<int>)=
    while x>0 do
        printfn "%d" x
        x <- x-1

let mutable x = 5
f &x
```

Comment: what if I want to keep the "While" loop?

Comment: I changed my answer to address this.

Comment: Be warned that `byref` has some quirks which makes it difficult to use generically.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you want the final, mutated value of `x` to be passed back to the caller of the function or mutate it only locally.

For local-only mutation, just declare another variable, which would be mutable, but initially will have the value of `x`:

```
let f x =
    let mutable i = x
    while i>0 do
      printfn "%d" i
      i <- i-1
```

For passing the result back to the caller, you can use a ref-cell:

```
let f (x: int ref) =
    while x.Value>0 do
      printfn "%d" x.Value
      x := x.Value - 1
```

Note that now you have to refer to the ref-cell contents via the `.Value` property (or you can instead use operator `!`, as in `x := !x - 1`), and the mutation is now done via `:=`. Plus, the consumer of such function now has to create a ref-cell before passing it in:

```
let x = ref 5
f x
printfn "%d" x.Value  // prints "0"
```

---

Having said that, I must point out that mutation is generally less reliable, more error-prone than pure values. The normal way to write "loops" in pure functional programming is via recursion:

```
let rec f x = 
    if x > 0 then
        printf "%d" x
        f (x-1)
```

Here, each call to `f` makes another call to `f` with the value of `x` decreased by `1`. This will have the same effect as the loop, but now there is no mutation, which means easier debugging and testing.

Comment: Just saw your answer. Is quarantine making us a hivemind?

Comment: P.S. Your loop is missing a `rec`

Comment: Thanks, fixed that